# Android: how can I change a process name in C language?

Tags: android, c, linux, process, rename

My Android program would starts a process written in C language. I need to modify this process' name.

I used `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)` and it changed `/proc/$pid/status`, but `/proc/$pid/cmdline` did not changed.

I searched and found out that I can modify the value of `argv[0]`, but I don't know how to do this in an Android program.

Comment: Modifying `argv[0]` can only be done inside the C program. (`argv` is the canonical name of the array which contains a C program's arguments, in its `main` function.)

Comment: Overall, modifying the name of a process after it has started varies by operating system, and is rather flaky. Can you create a symlink to it (with your favorite name) instead, and call that? Are you sure you need to do this? :-)

Comment: to jpaugh: Thanks for you answer. My android process has a service and this service create a process in c language. When the service was killed and other process wanted to startService, startService would fail, because the c process has the same name with the service process. That is why I have to modify the name of the c process.

Comment: Ok. Then that's your real problem. You might want to search for/ask that instead, since there might be a way to solve your problem without renaming. I don't know much about Android services, but mucking with process meta-data can be a fickle thing

Comment: OK. I ask a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207065/android-startservice-failed-because-a-c-program-has-the-same-name-with-the-serv

Answer (score 0):

I use the "environ" pointer to find the argv[0] and change the name of process successfully.

Comment: hello can you please elaborate? What is the "environ" pointer?