# Android: startService failed because a c program has the same name with the service process

Tags: android, c, linux, service

My android process has a service and this service create a process in c language. When the service was killed and other process wanted to startService, startService would fail, because the c process has the same name with the service process.

(startService would return ComponentName, but a TransactionTooLargeException would be thrown. This TransactionTooLargeException is not caused by a Intent with too much data, because when I did not create the c process, startService worked normally.)

I try to modify the name of the c process to solve this problem, but I can't change the name of this c process. I used`"prctl(PR_SET_NAME)"` and it changed `/proc/$pid/status`, but `/proc/$pid/cmdline` did not changed. And I can't/don't know how to change `argv[0]` in an android program.

How can I solve this problem? Change the name of c process or something else?

Comment: I found it didnt work wether the name of c process is same with service process or not. When the service process start a child process in c process and then the service process exit and the child process keeps running, other app can not use startService to start the service. When startService was called, TransactionTooLargeException is thrown.

Comment: After you explained the situation more thoroughly, I believe the problem is, you need to shut down the existing C process before starting a new one. Can you save the PID to a file, and then kill it when your service shuts down?

Comment: Yes, I can stop the c process before I start a new service. Thanks.